# given the sequence: 2,-6,12,-20,30,-42,...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence: $2,-6,12,-20,30,-42,... $

How can i find the $S_n$ term of that sequence? (the sum of the $n$ first terms)

I can see that the differences without the sign is an arithmetic progression,

and can get to $a_n$ but can't see how can i get to the $S_n$ term because of that sign.

thanks.

**EDIT**: im sorry i need to find $s_n$ not as i wrote before.

**UPDATE**: thanks to @mathlove the solution is:

$S_n=-\frac{n(n+2)}{2}\ \ \ \ \text{($n$ is even)}$

$S_n=\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}\ \ \ \ \text{($n$ is odd)}$.

I'm asking if we can write those two terms as one by some manipulation.

thanks!

Comment: $-a$=$(-1)\times a$, $(-1)\times(-1)=1$

Comment: i edited that question, sorry for that. i need to find $S_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 
$$|a_n|=n(n+1)(\text{why?}),$$
we have
$$a_n=(-1)^{n-1}n(n+1).$$

**EDIT 2** : If you want $S_n$, you can use the followings :
$$a_{2k-1}=2k(2k-1), \ \ a_{2k}=-2k(2k+1)$$
where $k=1,2,3,\cdots.$

For exmaple, if you want $S_{10}$, you'll see
$$S_{10}=(a_1+a_3+\cdots +a_9)+(a_2+a_4+\cdots +a_{10})$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{5}2k(2k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{5}\{-2k(2k+1)\}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{5}\{(4k^2-2k)-(4k^2+2k)\}=\sum_{k=1}^{5}(-4k)=-4(1+2+3+4+5).$$

**EDIT 2** : We can have an explicit form of $S_n$.
$$S_n=-\frac{n(n+2)}{2}\ \ \ \ \text{($n$ is even)}$$
$$S_n=\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}\ \ \ \ \text{($n$ is odd)}.$$

Comment: thanks but i can't see how do you get to the sum of $s_n$ by those two new terms.

Comment: @abi: I added a bit again. Does this help?

Comment: if it were all numbers so maybe i could see the pattern but i can see it whit those two terms even if i arrange them by even and odd.

Comment: @abi: I added a bit again.

Comment: oh now i see that thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: but how did you get $a_{2k-1}$, $a_{2k}$?

Comment: Consider $|a_n|$. Letting $b_n=|a_{n+1}|-|a_n|$, $b_n=2n+2.$ Do you think you can continue this?

Comment: so for $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{0.5n}2k(2k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{0.5n}\{-2k(2k+1)\}$?

Comment: Not really. What you wrote is the formula for the case that $n$ is even. The formula for the case that $n$ is odd is $S_{2n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k(2k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\{-2k(2k+1)\}.$ Notice a small difference.

Comment: sorry, a bit mistake. Maybe you prefer to the following form for the case that $n$ is odd: $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}2k(2k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}\{-2k(2k+1)\}$.

Comment: but how can i write sum bu only one term without the two cases? i would very appreciate if you could show me that in you answer, anyways thanks a lot i learned from it!

Comment: We can get $S_n=-n(n+2)/2$ for the case that $n$ is even. and...odd case is...

Comment: we can't get just one $S_n$ by putting something like $(-1)^n$?

Comment: @abi : I don't think so. I finally got the formula. see my answer.

Comment: got it. it was a pleasure thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like $a_n=(-1)^n|a_n|$ (alternating positive and negative), so if you know an expression for $|a_n|$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Interpolating (using Newton Interpolation) on the points $b_1 = 2, b_2=6, b_3=12, b_4=20, b_5=30,...$ gives $b_n$ = $n^2 + n$.

Adding in the alternating signs, we get $a_n = (-1)^{n+1}(n^2 + n)$